# Popup Manipulation

Tags: java, exception, selenium, file-upload, popupwindow

I'm new to Selenium and i'm trying to Upload the Document inside the Popup when the "Upload Document" has Clicked.

I've run the Application in the Selenium IDE and Export the Test case as Junit 4/ WebDriver. And imported into Eclipse and running the Same it works well.

When we bit altered the code and tried to run the Same uploading concept were it says that

```
"NoSuchElementException" Unable to locate element{"method":"id","selector":"file_upload"}.
```

Below this i've attached the corresponding html and its popup box.

[image]

Selenium code which i used listed below:

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.tab_submit.register_irb_complete_button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("file_upload")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("file_upload")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\XXX\\Downloads\\loremipsum.docx");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.close")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#irb_documents > #irb_next")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the `id` field of the input tag is "file_upload_0", not "file_upload". Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Hi HSquirrel, id="file_upload_"+i+ will be auto generated when so many files need to upload so generally i used it as file_upload. So in case i need to write a function to click and upload several times.

Kindly help me out to know the upload using dynamic id's. Please

Answer (score 0):

First You need to be sure that you arr working with the new Window (popup) and not the Default one. Once you handle it, you can try to select and Upload your file. Also keep in mind that the new UploadWindow may require additional actions in order for you to upload successfully. In some cases all you need to do is use the **sendKeys** *command* and to type the local path of the file in the input file field, but some cases require [AutoIT](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/).